# ArrayList not storing a value

Tags: java, arraylist

In my main, I am asking the user 2 questions. Both questions have 2 correct answers, which is choice number 2 and 4. Whenever I run the Code and select option 2(for both questions), it results in false. If I run the program and select option 4, it results in true. Both options 2 and 4 are correct. I feel as if the issue is due to my UpdateChoices method(located in MultiCheck class), but I don't know why. I used an ArrayList to save the correct choices, but the first correct choice (option 2) is not saved, resulting in it displaying false. Is there a reason why the first option isn't saved in the ArrayList? My output window is posted below the code.

This is the code I have: **Main**

```
package pa4_pandeyay;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyQuestionDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    MultiCheck first = new MultiCheck();
    first.setText("Which number below is prime?");
    first.UpdateChoices("4", false);
    first.UpdateChoices("3", true);
    first.UpdateChoices("12", false);
    first.UpdateChoices("7", true);
    first.UpdateChoices("8", false);


    MultiCheck second = new MultiCheck();
    second.setText("Which number below multiplied equals to 12?");
    second.UpdateChoices("4 * 4", false);
    second.UpdateChoices("12 * 1", true);
    second.UpdateChoices("12 * 2", false);
    second.UpdateChoices("-6 * -2", true);
    second.UpdateChoices("0 * 12", false);

    presentQuestion(first); 
    presentQuestion(second);

}

public static void presentQuestion(MultiCheck x){
    x.display();
    System.out.print("Your answer: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(x.checkAnswer(response));
}
}
```

Java class Question.java

```
package pa4_pandeyay;

public class Question {
    private String text;
    private String answer;
    // Create a constructor
    public Question(){
        text = "";
        answer = "";
    }   
    // Set the question text
    public void setText(String questionText){
        text = questionText;
    }
    //Set the answer text
    public void setAnswer(String correctAnswer){
        answer = correctAnswer;        
    }
    // Check the respond with the actual correct answer
    public boolean checkAnswer(String response){
        return response.equals(answer);
    }
    public String getText(){
        return text; // since variable text it private, we need to create a get method in order to access the private variable
    }
    // Diplay question to the user:  
    public void display(){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Java class MultiCheck:

```
    package pa4_pandeyay;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MultiCheck extends Question{
private ArrayList<String> answerChoices;

public MultiCheck(){
    super(); 
    answerChoices = new ArrayList<String>();
}
public void UpdateChoices (String choice, boolean correct){ // check the asnwers and save the 'true' answers
    answerChoices.add(choice);
    if (correct == true)
    {
        //convert choices.size() to string
        String choiceString = "" + answerChoices.size();
        setAnswer(choiceString);
    }   
}
// when calling display, this method will be called.
@Override
public void display(){
    System.out.println(getText());
    // Display the answer choices
    for( int i =0; i< answerChoices.size(); i++){
        int choiceNumber =  i + 1;
        System.out.println(choiceNumber + " : " + answerChoices.get(i));
    }
}
```

[image: Output window]

Comment: Note that standard Java conventions call for methods to be in camelCase - so `UpdateChoices()` should be `updateChoices()`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I will change that in my code.

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code. For each MultiCheck you only store one correct answer.  If you do a printout of each MulticCheck you will see what I mean.  Instead of answerChoices being an array of Strings you could make it an array of Questions.

Comment: How does answerChoices only store 1 answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Question class can only store one correct answer by `setAnswer()`. If you have multiple correct answers, then they will override each other so that only the last one is finally in memory.